# Referencing .Net Framework 4.8 Class Library in .Net Core 3.0 Project

Tags: .net, .net-core

It is clear that it is not possible to reference .Net Standard 2.1 or .Net Core 3.0  in .NET Framework 4.8 project. If I add a .Net 4.8 class library into my .Net Core 3.0 project it seems to work. My .Net Core WPF application seems OK.

I am trying to figure out if any side effects may arise. I could not get a clear result. The question is that should I reference .Net 4.8 in my .Net core 3.0 app or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reference .net 4.8 in your .net core 3.0 app. The only drawback is that your app will now depend also on .net 4.8, so your users will need to have that. It might be relevant if you want to target for example Linux, but since you mentioned WPF - I asume you are only targeting windows anyway.

Comment: Should not be provided as an answer. Clearly an opinion based

Comment: Opinion based? Are u kidding me? You either CAN or CANNOT reference .net 4.8 lib in a .net core app. The answer is: Yes, you can. Are there any side effects? Yes there are (as stated in the answer), but it depends on the targeted OS. What is opinion based here?